# Windows executable file generated by PyGame + PyInstaller gives me "No such file or directory" error

Tags: python-2.7, pygame, executable, pyinstaller

I have first tried to create my original game sample using Pygame.

I have traced the instruction written in the Web site below:

https://irwinkwan.com/2013/04/29/python-executables-pyinstaller-and-a-48-hour-game-design-compo/

Specifically,

1. I created "myFile" class something like following and read every file (.txt, .png, .mp3, etc...) using this class

#### myFile Class

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import sys

class myFile():
    def resource_path(self, relative):
        if hasattr(sys, "_MEIPASS"):
            return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative)
    return os.path.join(relative)

### code where I read something ###
myfile = myFIle()
filename = myfile.resource_path(os.path.join("some dir", "somefile"        
+ "extension")
```

2. I typed command below to create .spec file (myRPG.py contains main)

   `pyinstaller --onefile myRPG.py`
3. I modified .spec file so exe object include Trees (I store data files in separate
   directories such as data, image, and so on)

#### myRPG.spec file

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['myRPG.py'],
    pathex=['C:\\mygame\\mygame'],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
    cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
Tree('bgm', prefix='bgm'),
Tree('charachip', prefix='charachip'),
Tree('data', prefix='data'),
Tree('image', prefix='image'),
Tree('mapchip', prefix='mapchip'),
Tree('se', prefix='se'),
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    name='myRPG',
    debug=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True )
```

4. I did rebuild my package using modified .spec file

   `pyinstaller myRPG.spec`
5. When I execute myRPG.exe file, I got the error below

   ```
   C:\mygame\mygame\dist>myRPG.exe
   [Errno 2] No such file or directory:  
      'C:\\Users\\bggfr\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI64~1\\item.data' IO Errorが発生しました。

   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "myRPG.py", line 606, in <module>
   File "myRPG.py", line 37, in __init__
   File "myItemList.py", line 11, in __init__
   File "myItemList.py", line 33, in load
   UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fp' referenced before assignment
   Failed to execute script myRPG
   ```

I believe that I properly specify the directories where data is expanded since I use the function that checks _MEIPASS but it does not work.

I have also tried to use "added_files" instead of Tree did not help for me at all. ”a.datas" may work for small number of files but I do not want to specify all the files I'm going to use, because it will be over hundreds of thousands of files.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.pajamaprogrammer.com/2015/11/convert-python-35-script-py-to-windows.html) is a very helpful page that I used when converting my pygame program into an executable.

In short:

1. [Here](https://sites.google.com/site/pydatalog/python/pip-for-windows) is the place where you can download pyInstaller. Click on the download button under "Installation." Wait for it to download, then run it.
2. Type this into the popup where it says command: `venv -c -i pyi-env-name`. The reason for this is stated in the page mentioned at the top.
3. If you have pyInstaller installed already, type `pyinstaller --version` to make sure. If you don't, type `pip install PyInstaller`. If this doesn't work, look at step 7 in the guide up top.
4. Make sure that you put a copy of your program in the folder that it says on the command line.
5. If you want a zip with the exe and all necessary files in it type `pyinstaller` and then the name of your program, complete with the `.py` extension. However, if you want an exe that doesn't need all of the extra files in the zip that you can just run by itself, type `pyinstaller --onefile --windowed` and then the name of your program, complete with the extension of `.py`.
6. Once you have done this, the exe will appear in a `dist` folder inside of the one where you placed your program in step 3.

This is how it worked for me, and I apologize if I have misinformed you. Be sure to upvote/mark as answered if this works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And I'm very sorry that I missed only one line to read file with resource_path function. That's what wrong with my code.